# unoconv: export Excel file to PDF without any scripting

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, export

How to hide page header and footer during the Excel file export with `unoconv`?

I've tried to use a template (narrow margins, disabled header, disabled footer), but it does not work. I mean: margins become narrow, but I still can see header and footer.

Command I use to export:

```
$ unoconv -d spreadsheet -f pdf -t margins.ots -v document.xml
```

where

- document.xml is XML structured Excel file
- margins.ots is a template with narrow margins and disabled header/footer

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to hide Excel header and footer with unoconv. Instead, you should set them to empty strings in the Excel file itself before passing it to unoconv.

For example, if you generate Excel files with python xlwt, you can do this:

```
sheet = book.get_sheet(0)
sheet.header_str = ''
sheet.footer_str = ''
```